# Detect stalling Motor in the new EV3 Education Classroom

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, programming, motor, software

I have a gripper that should automatically stop closing when an object is grabbed. I achieved this in the older EV3 Home Edition by reading the motor current and comparing it to normal values. If it differed, the action would be stopped because the gripper arms caught the object and the motor 'stalled.' I'm keen on achieving this by reading the motor values as I dont have enough touch sensors on hand.

Now, while migrating to the newer Scratch-like version of the EV3 App, I cannot find a block that serves this purpose. I did some research but found nothing(regarding the newer version at least), except for this post: [Read power usage and respond when motor is straining](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10881/read-power-usage-and-respond-when-motor-is-straining) which, as far as I understood correctly, does not answer my question.

[image: Image of my old and working code, with the block in question marked]

Is there a block in the newer Mindstorms Classroom version that has similar functionality that I've just overlooked, or are there some mechanisms I can use that have the same result/effect as my current programm in the older version?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only two motor feedback blocks in EV3 Classroom, one that measures the motor position and one that measured the motor speed.

[image: screenshot of EV3 Classroom motor feedback blocks]

When a motor is stalling or is overloaded, the measured speed will be less than the requested speed, so you should be able to use that to implement stall detection.